# Connect esp32 hardware to mobile app (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: esp32, bluetooth, mobile-applications

I'm designing some SmartLED controller (hardware/server) which can turn on/off some LED strips and do some nice effects etc. and it works on ESP32 chip.

Now, I was starting to write Xamarin.Forms mobile app for communicating between my mobile app and ESP32 (it will use WLED JSON API), but before using the API over HTTPS (wifi), I want to do a pairing process for this controller.

- Option1 - SmartConfig

  I was testing this over some CLI and some example code for ESP32, it partially works. When I do it all on single laptop machine it works, but when I start ESP32 on my desktop PC, and start CLI C# example code on another machine it doesn't work (can't find a device).
- Option2 - Improv standard from esphome

  I tried to look for some code, but documentation is very very poor
- Option3 - AP emitting from hardware, web server that prompts the user for SSID and password for current wifi.
- Option4 - BLE communication (if no wifi, or user doesn't want to hookup controller to the wifi) - this will be my next scope

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: which standard should I use for the pairing process between IoT device and my xamarin mobile app?